# getting duplicate category name in product listing page magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento-1.9

I want to show current category on product listing page 
[image: As this image]

But after applying product  filter it's showing category 2 time 
[image: As this image]

the code im using to get categroy is:

```
<?php 

if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
$name = $category->getName()
} else {
// either show nothing or fall back to load the product categories and pick 
one }
?>
<?php echo '<h1 style="font-size: 25px; color: #393b3d;">'.$this- 
>escapeHtml($name).'</h1>'; ?>
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this error?
thanks :)

Comment: are you using ajax based layered navigation filter?

Comment: Problem is that category name rendered two times after using layered navigation check template/catalog/category/view.phtml file for $_category->getname();

Comment: thanks its worked :P